# Reflection or dynamic methods

Tags: php

What is the best practice?

```
$method = 'setId';
```

with reflection

```
$userClass = new ReflectionClass(User::class);
$userClass->getMethod($method)->invoke($user, [ 45 ]);
```

or dynamically

```
$user->$method(45);
```

Exactly in this case, without checking on method existence

Comment: Well, just by looking at the code involved, I would think the answer is clear. If the method doesn't exist you will get an error anyway.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware for me, first variant more understandable and It looks prettier. But second variant shorter, that's why I asked what is more correct would be to use. Or this question rely on taste?

Comment: If you like reflection more (for example code you gave) then it apears that answer is a matter of taste. Although I don't think you'll be liked for inventig sophisticated looking code for something as trivial as dynamic method. I also assume that you've spent some time on more fundamental question: *Do I really need this?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in PHP that prevents scalar type declarations to be interpreted strictly when a function or method is invoked using the Reflection API.

Example:

```
class C
{
    public function m(string $x)
    {
        var_dump($x);
    }
}
```

Calling via reflections (don't do this!)

```
declare(strict_types=1);

$object = new C();
$arguments = [1];

$method = new ReflectionMethod($object, 'm');
$method->invokeArgs($object, $arguments);
```

The result:

```
string(1) "1"
```

**Conclusion**: Don't use Reflection to invoke a method.

[Source](https://thephp.cc/news/2018/02/indirect-invocation-considered-harmful)