# Using strict_types=1 with dependency container useless?

Tags: php, types, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, thephpleague

Consider this simple class:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

class Blog
{
    private $user;

    public function __construct(string $user)
    {       
        $this->user = $user;    
    }

    public function post ()
    {
        return 'New post by '.$this->user;      
    }
}
```

Using basic dependency injection works fine:

```
$blog = new Blog('Bob');
echo $blog->post();
// no errors, works as expected

$blog = new Blog(7);
echo $blog->post();
// fatal errors with TypeError, works as expected
```

But when using a dependency container like [league\container](https://container.thephpleague.com/3.x/) the strict_types declaration is ignored?

```
$container = new League\Container\Container;
$container->add(Blog::class)->addArgument(7);
$foo = $container->get(Blog::class);
echo $foo->post();
// I passed `7` in the parameter, it doesn't work as expected
//  because it should've fatal error with TypeError because `7` is not a string
```

A quick view of the `src` folder of `league\container` reveals it's also using `declare(strict_types=1);` in all of its files. That said, I'm not sure if it's possible for the container to detect the parameter types of the class its initiating. If it's not possible then using `declare(strict_types=1);` is useless in this case?

Comment: @PaulCrovella I see I guess that means `league\container` needs to refactor and put that functionality?

Comment: The container library uses Reflection. This is a known bug in PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49140881/1461181

Comment: @DanielO I see. Do you recommend another DI container library that respects scalar type hints?

Comment: Afaik, all (PHP) DI libraries make use of reflection. Have you tried [PHP-DI](http://php-di.org/)? The (invalid) result should be the same.

Comment: Adding some info to @user3942918's comment: the `declare` construct **affect the file that uses it and all child files**. I.e., if file `K.php` uses `declare` and includes file `C.php` and `D.php`, then  `C.php` and `D.php` are affected by the *K*'s `declare`. And if file `A.php` includes file `K.php`, file `A.php` does **not** know about *K*'s `declare` constructor.